# How do I make a script that creates acronyms from input in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I found another solution to this question but it uses Python 2.7

```
import re

words = "internet explorer 10"
print re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z])[a-z,A-Z]+\s*",r"\1",words).upper()
```

^^ this is the solution they used for Python 2.7, I edited it to look more like this:

```
import re

words = input()
print re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z])[a-z,A-Z]+\s*",r"\1",words).upper()
```

I want to be able to have a user's input turned into the acronym grabbing all the first letters to make it.

Comment: No idea what you are trying to achieve, but change `print ...` to `print(...)` and you got a working Python 3 code.

Comment: As DeepSapce said: print(re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z])[a-z,A-Z]+\s*",r"\1", words).upper())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
# creates acronyms

text = input("Enter your words to 'acronymize' \n" + ">>> ")
acronym = ""

textArr = text.split(" ")

for word in textArr:
    if not word.startswith(("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "0")):
        letter = word[0]
        acronym += letter.upper()
    elif word.startswith(("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "0")):
        acronym += " " + word + " "

print(acronym)
```

Comment: so this code works super great however when i make the text = input() it gives me errors back

Comment: @kreig can you edit your comment and add the error? I may be able to edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @kreig I may have fixed your error, I found a major problem and fixed it. I needed to have commas instead of 'or' statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
words = input()
print(re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z])[a-z,A-Z]+\s*",r"\1", words).upper())
```